# How do I use this custom drawable class?

Tags: java, android, drawable

Im fairly new to android programming so im not sure on this.

Im trying to set a png as a background but the image is stretching when i use `android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd"` in my layout xml file

I found this custom class here http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=27178#27178 but im not sure how to use it in my code.
Ive copied the code into its own class file and no errors are present.

How do I set the background to the drawable above using this class?

NB: I have abandoned this approach and gone with something much simpler. The answers below did give clues along with some other stackoverflow questions. Answer is below.

Comment: use `View.setBackground()` method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result can be achieved using scale drawables instead

bkgrnd.xml (drawable xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/bkgrnd"
android:scaleGravity="clip_horizontal"
android:scaleHeight="100%"
android:scaleWidth="100%"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout.xml

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/bkgrnd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one it will help you.

```
android:src="@drawable/bkgrnd"
```

Comment: Using this just made the background image disappear

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, declare an ImageView like this

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now the app won't run. Im getting a "The following classes could not be instantiated error"

Comment: I also get java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:my.package.NonScalingBackgroundDrawable.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)

Comment: It wasn't a good solution for your problem, sorry. Take a look to my answer again. I've edited it